# Using navigation stack without laser/point cloud

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am currently using the navigation stack for simulation with a fake laser. However, I'd like to remove the laser since I plan on using data from a motion capture system. The entire area where the robot is moving can be precisely check for obstacle without the laser or a local costmap and a map (nav_msgs/occupancygrid) is generated. Every time I try to remove it one way or another, I get endless warnings of "The base_scan observation buffer has not been updated for X seconds, and it should be updated every 0.40 seconds." and "[/move_base_node]:Sensor data is out of date, we're not going to allow commanding of the base for safety", so nothing moves.
Is it possible to use this stack without a laser/point cloud?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173204/using-navigation-stack-without-laser/point-cloud/) by [TopSecret](https://answers.ros.org/users/11111/topsecret/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2014-06-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In Hydro, the obstacle avoidance behavior of the nav stack is determined by which costmaps are in use. In theory, you should be able to configure the nav stack to use only static costmaps.

If you're trying different configurations without restarting, you may find that you need to clear out the parameter server between runs to make sure you get a clean configuration. You can either restart your roscore, or clear out just the move base configuration with something like `rosparam delete /move_base`

I don't believe this is possible in earlier versions of the nav stack, before Hydro.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1